# Responsive HTML theme design framework that supports 2048px resolution

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am looking for a responsive HTML theme design framework that supports 2048px resolution (iPad retina display)-- most frameworks stop at 1280px.

If there is no such framework, then how do I extend an existing framework (like Twitter Bootstrap) so that it supports 2048px?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap responsive design supports 1200px and up. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Billy Moat said, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) supports high resolutions; so does [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

As an aside, I found it odd that you mention the iPad retina. Did you know that while the retina iPad has a 2048px resolution, it has the same CSS pixel resolution as the original iPad? [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/) sums it up nicely.